# How to replace a match with an entire file in BASH?

Tags: bash, replace

I have a line like this:

INPUT file1

How can I get bash to read that line and directly copy in the contents of "file1.txt" in place of that line? Or if it sees: `INPUT file2` on a line, put in `file2.txt" etc.

The best I can do is a lot of `tr` commands, to paste the file together, but that seems an overly complicated solution.

'sed' also replaces lines with strings, but I don't know how to input the entire content of a file, which can be hundreds of lines into the replacement.

Comment: Most operating systems can't replace file contents with text of different size.  Every answer will boil down to "write everything to a new temporary file, then replace the original file with the temporary".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems pretty straightforward with `awk`.  You may want to handle errors differently/more gracefully, but:

```
$ cat file1
Line 1 of file 1
$ cat file2
Line 1 of file 2
$ cat input
This is some content
INPUT file1
This is more content
INPUT file2
This file does not exist
INPUT file3
$ awk '$1=="INPUT" {system("cat " $2); next}1' input
This is some content
Line 1 of file 1
This is more content
Line 1 of file 2
This file does not exist
cat: file3: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this in pure Bash, here's an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if (( $# < 1 )); then
    echo "Usage: ${0##*/} FILE..."
    exit 2
fi

for file; do
    readarray -t lines < "${file}"
    for line in "${lines[@]}"; do
        if [[ "${line}" == "INPUT "* ]]; then
            cat "${line#"INPUT "}"
            continue
        fi
        echo "${line}"
    done > "${file}"
done
```

Save to file and run like this: `./script.sh input.txt` (where `input.txt` is a file containing text mixed with `INPUT <file>` statements).

Answer (score 1):

A perl one-liner, using the CPAN module [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny)

```sh
perl -MPath::Tiny -pe 's/INPUT (\w+)/path("$1.txt")->slurp/e' input_file
```

use `perl -i -M...` to edit the file in-place.

Answer (score 1):

Not the most efficient possible way, but as an exercise I made a file to edit named `x` and a couple of input sources named `t1` & `t2`.

```
$: cat x
a
INPUT t2
b
INPUT t1
c
$: while read k f;do sed -ni "/$k $f/!p; /$k $f/r $f" x;done< <( grep INPUT x )
$: cat x
a

here's
 ==> t2

b

this
is
file ==> t1

c
```

Yes, the blank lines were in the INPUT files.
This will `sed` your base file repeatedly, though.
The `awk` solution given is better, as it only reads through it once.

Answer (score 0):

Sed solution similar to awk given erlier:

```
$ cat f 
test1

INPUT f1

test2

INPUT f2

test3

$ cat f1
new string 1

$ cat f2
new string 2

$ sed 's/INPUT \(.*\)/cat \1/e' f
test1

new string 1

test2

new string 2

test3
```

Bash variant

```
while read -r line; do
    [[ $line =~ INPUT.* ]] && { tmp=($BASH_REMATCH); cat ${tmp[1]}; } || echo $line
done < f
```